# DNN DDRMenu xslt template test if previous item was selected

Tags: xslt, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I need to know if the previous node was a @selected node.  I need to basically mark the next/following node if it exists with a special css class.

I tried the following code and it threw an exception

```
<xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling:@selected = 1)">next</xsl:if>
```

Here is a copy of the xslt with your suggestion in it: http://pastebin.com/gANkhz2g

The menu is the standard menu:

```
<dnn:MENU id="nameMenu" MenuStyle="Simple" runat="Server"/>
```

I honestly do not know the xml that is produced by that control.

Comment: `<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/@selected">next</xsl:if>`

Comment: That added "next" to the selected node and everything after it.

Comment: If you post an actual stylesheet and example XML, it'll be easier to test.

Comment: Alf,  I have updated my question with links to the xslt and information about the control.

Comment: Without seeing the XML I can't say for sure, but I suspect this is what you're looking for: `<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node[1]/@selected = 1">next</xsl:if>`

Comment: That worked brilliantly.  Can you officially make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preceding-sibling::node[1]` to select the first (in reverse order) preceding sibling named "node":

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node[1]/@selected = 1">next</xsl:if>
```